# Finding Length of a vector

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Given the vector $v =(1,3,5,7,9)$ what is the ℓ1 length of $v$.
I have tried using the below formula:

$$|a| = \sqrt{a_x^2 + a_y^2 + a_z^2}$$

however this gives me an answer as $12.84$ whereas the correct answer is $25$, is there something incorrect the way I have calculated.
Referred to the [Website](https://onlinemschool.com/math/library/vector/length/)

Comment: That website tells you the formula for the length of a two-domensional vector and for a three-dimensional vector. You have a five-dimensional vector. What do you _think_ the formula looks like?

Comment: The [$\ell_p$ norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#The_p-norm_in_finite_dimensions) (it is usually called $\ell_p$ norm or simply $p$-norm instead of $\ell_p$ length) of a vector $(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is
$\left(\sum_{k=1}^n |a_k|^p\right)^{1/p}$. You have computed the $\ell_2$ norm of the vector, not the $\ell_1$ norm $\left(|1| + |3| + |5| + |7| + |9|\right)^{1/1} = 25$.

Comment: @achillehui I don't even think the calculation for the euclidean norm is correct. He appears to have used the three-dimensional version. How he managed this for five quantities  I cannot imagine.

Comment: @Allawonder the formula OP persented here is incorrect but the value of euclidean norm looks correct $\sqrt{1^2 + 3^2 + 5^2 + 7^2 + 9^2} = \sqrt{165} \approx 12.8452...$

Comment: Who asked you to find the $\ell_1$ length of $v$? To find a formula, you should refer to the textbook and/or course notes assigned by the person who asked the question, not to some random web page that doesn't even mention "$\ell_1$".

Comment: @achillehui Oh, I see now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @achille hui has mentioned, what you want here is simply to add the lengths of all the coordinates -- this is the $\ell_1$ length needed. Clearly this is just the sum of all the coordinates given, since they're all positive. It's well known that the sum of the first $n$ odd numbers is $n^2,$ hence the result $25.$